# Setting sling:resourceSuperType to a carousel and remove property not working in AEM 6.1

Tags: aem

I have a test web page that contains one component, a carousel. 
That component was copied from `/libs/foundation/components/carousel` and what i have modified from the copied component was the property:
sling:resourceSuperType from `foundation/components/list` to `foundation/components/carousel`.

My next step was to remove a property from the touch dialog (the property `Controls Style`).
My problem is that in my web page i keep seeing this property even when it was deleted.

Is this because the `resourceSuperType` is `foundation/components/carousel` and because this component stills have the property i'm seeing in the dialog?

This behavior was not like this in AEM 5.

My intention was to copy the component, keep the inheritance (resourceSuperType) and modify the copied component.

What i'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Making some tests i figure out that in AEM 6.0 if i delete a property of the carousel (my copied carousel), the property doesn't appear. BUT in AEM 6.1 the property appears. Where can i found this change between the two versions? or is something else?

Answer (score 1):

When creating an overlay, you're going to find all properties from the original component even if they don't exist in the overlay.

You'll have to explicitly remove the property by adding the `sling:hideProperties` property of type `String[]` to your overlay. This will allow you to hide the values otherwise inherited from the node from `/libs` that you're trying to overlay.

I think you'll find the descriptions of various use cases for the `sling:hideProperties` property in [the documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/platform/overlays.html) quite useful.

Comment: is this something new in AEM 6.1? because a coworker told me that this in previous versions of AEM doesn't work like that.

Comment: @Phoenix_uy to be honest, I haven't used it. I was told about this property by a coworker a while ago.  When I saw your question, I recalled having talked about this and did a quick search in the docs. At a glance, I can't find a mention of this property in the 5.6.1 documentation so maybe it's just new.

Comment: When you say the "overlay".. what is it? i have added this property to the root of my copied carousel component but with out luck

Comment: @Phoenix_uy try adding it to the node that has the property you're trying to remove. That would be the one in the dialog if I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As part of of it's resource resolution process, the Sling Resource Resolver has search paths that it looks in to locate a resource.

The two most common search paths are `/apps` and  `/libs`. With the /apps path taking precedence. The most common usage of this in `sling:resourceType` where the value is defined as the path below one of these search paths. In your case having a sling:resourceType of `foundation/components/carousel` would originally return the OOTB components under /libs and when you copied it to the /apps directory it would return the component you put under /apps.

This concept of replacing the existing component with your own component is called an **overlay** another method is called **extending** an component where you define a `sling:resourceSuperType` which, if a resource is not found in the existing path, will pass the request to the superType to see if the resource can be found there.

Before 6.0 this concept of overlay applied only to resource. Which is a node that contains properties (simplistically speaking.) And in most common usage you have to reflect the majority of the component into the new search path to get what you are trying to do.

Starting in 6.0 there was a new concept of a merged resource. That would combine the values of a resource located in multiple search paths. This allowed you to modify or alter the functionality of a component without replicating everything else. You could just change a property at a particular level.

None of this happens automatically. To get this functionality the component needs to be aware of the ResourceMergerApi and use that API when attempting to resolve resources for it to use.

That's why the documentation mentions granite. Granite refers to the new components being written by Adobe that uses the TouchUI and is aware of this new API. With each new release more and more older components are being replaced by the new TouchUI based ones that supports resource merging. Including the carousel.